# Linux Mint - Glitch in Screen Recording video files

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gnu-screen, video, recording

I am new to Linux, and most things seem to work fine; but it is not the case of Screen Recording. I have tried with the following programs:

- OBS Studio
- Voko Screen
- Kazam

And I have tried with the following video formats;

- FLV
- MP4
- MKV

And I have tried with the default media player and with VLC

But the issue is always the same; Black flashes in the video, in different areas of the screen. When recording, you cannot see them, but when watching the video you recorded, there they are. I uploaded an example of a recording to [youtube here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cG6uCfr6TxY&feature=youtu.be)

The bug seems to happen more often when I close, open, maximize or minimize windows while recording.

How could I fix it?

EDIT: This is what I get after writing "inxi -G"

> Graphics:  Card: Intel 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
>              Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
>              Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
>              GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0

The kernel is (Correct me if I put the wrong information): 4.4.0-53-generic

And I am using Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

Comment: would you care to add your version of kernel, mint itself and what drivers for what video card are in use?

Comment: Yes, this is almost certainly an issue with your graphics driver. Please  [edit] your question and tell us what graphics card you are using and what driver. If you don't know how to get this information, open a terminal and install `inxi` (run `sudo apt-get install inxi`) and then run `inxi -G` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Sure, I will edit in a sec

Answer (score 2):

With nvidia gpu problem is solved by turning off "flipping" from nvidia driver control panel (nvidia Xserver settings)